# How can add Image and Serial Port to combobox same time?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I use this code

```
foreach (string ports in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
                cmbComPort.Items.Add(ports);
            cmbComPort.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

for add serial port for combobox. But I want to add image same time with serial port name like this:

[image].

How can I make it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ComboBox' ItemTemplate-Property to design your ComboBox-Items:

```
<ComboBox
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" /> 
                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Folder/PictureName.Format"
            </StackPanel >
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```